# RegEx to get unique values from large file with duplicates

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I have a large XML-file that I want to extract unique values from. The values I'm looking for are placed in the XML-tag: ns3:order_id
To make it more complex, the file contains duplicates of order_id, and I'm only interested in geeting the unique order_id values.

I've been using RegEx to extract the values, this is the expression:

```
(?sm)(\<ns3:order_id>\d+\b)(?!.*\1\b)
```

The expression gives me what I need, BUT only if the file is way smaller. When I try this expression on the "big" file I receive: "Catastrophic backtracking has been detected and the execution of your expression has been halted." I guess it has with *, and I have tried different ways replacing it without success.

Is there any way to correct my expression so that I can collect the values?

As seen in the text above, I've tried several diffrent RegEx ways. The expression above works, but not in bigger files.

Comment: Why not extract all values not caring about duplicates and pipe to sort and uniq (or some other post-regex processing)? Also worth updating the question to clarify why you want to parse xml with a refer at all :)

Comment: You should really not use regex on XML files, regex is not meant for this in the majority of XML manipulation tasks.

Comment: I agree, there are better ways to read values from XML than using regex. See this famous (and funny) answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1288408

Comment: It sound like using xPath with "distinct-values" is a better way to go?